# Why there's 'This is not a zero-length file' in <head>

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-head

When I inspect a web page (even stackoverflow), I always see

```
<style type="text/css">/* This is not a zero-length file! */</style>
<style type="text/css">/* This is not a zero-length file! */</style>
```

(yes, twice) at the bottom of the `<head>` tag.

Google gives [no answer](https://www.google.be/#q=chrome+this+is+not+a+zero-length+file) about that...

Does it come from Chrome? What's the point?

### Edit

Thanks the others for the answer. This code was generated by the [Instant Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-translate/ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke) Chrome extension.

Comment: This will indeed be an extension problem. Just disable the one causing it (shouldn't be hard to find) and it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling your extensions and see if it remains. If it disappears, try enabling your extensions one by one, to find the culprit.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually added by [Instant Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-translate/ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke) Chrome extension.